# Is this a smart way to organize code in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

for the longest time I was writing all my code inside like this ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show_module').click(function(){

    });
     ...

});
```

putting all sorts of click handlers in there. But recently I was introduced to a new way of doing things and I wanted to get a feel for if its a smart way of going about it.

the idea is to have all the handlers in related functions and then have minimal code in document.ready above.

So for example ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    page_handler(); // other functions follow
});

function page_handler(){
    $('.show_module').click(function(){

    });
     ...
}
```

This seems to allow organization of related handlers in functions  and use document.ready as more of an initializer.

I know in JavaScript functions and variables are 'hoisted' before code starts executing so

```
do_something();
function do_something(){

}
```

works for this reason, since the function is ready to use before do_something() is actually called, even though it appears before the actual function definition.

I was wondering if the same thing happens here and how 'good' this idea/way of doing things is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will expose all your handlers to the global (`window`) scope, which may lead to clashes.

I prefer to do this...

```
(function($) {

 // Anything you do in here won't be attached to window.
 var a;

 // If you must have something global, set it explicitly
 window.doSomething = function() { ... }

 // We can also use $ for jQuery here, even if we have used jQuery.noConflict()
 $('body')...

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: why (function($){})(jquery);? and when you say 'clashes' ... can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: @concept47 I mean if you have a function `handleClick()` and your colleague also makes one, you will have a clash.

Comment: okay ... I like where you're going with this, but how do you deal with a case where you have a ton of handlers inside your (function($){})(jQuery); call? ... how would you split them out into functions on their own ... feel free to update your answer with that.

Comment: @concept47 Unless I need to, I keep the event handlers as anonymous functions so I don't pollute unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on:

**Do you want to reuse the functions?**
- If yes, your structure is a good way to do it

**How long is your code?**
- If your code is not too long and not use anywhere else. I think you don't need to break it into functions.

Comment: Sometimes, for really complex UI interactions, you can get many handlers which also happen to be lengthy so even though some of the functions aren't re-used, it seems like an easier way to organize the code

Answer (score 0):

I always put the functions **before** the document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

Which I would write in short-hand:

```
$(function() { ... });
```

Ideally it is better to have just one initialiser like above. [This](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) may be useful for you too if you want to write extensions/plugins in jQuery context.

Comment: Any particular reason why? The functions will be hoisted first either way and by putting the document ready first, someone looking at your code knows its there.